# Terraform Update an existing Lambda function was created on AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I want to update a my code on Lambda function.

I previous creating lambda function on aws console.

I do a creating terraform code for update my function existing but I received an error

I try using this block code

```
data "archive_file" "stop_ec2" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "src_dir/stop_ec2.py"
  output_path = "dest_dir/stop_ec2_upload.zip"
}

data "aws_lambda_function" "existing" {
  function_name = MyPocLambda
  role          = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  filename      = "dest_dir/stop_ec2_upload.zip"
  source_code_hash ="${data.archive_file.stop_ec2.output_base64sha256}"

}
```

My error says filename unsupported argument, filename is not expected here

it possible update lambda function using terafform data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/import) your lambda function to TF first. Then you will be able to modify it using TF code using [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) resource, not data source.